# How to get the UK timezone in PHP and detect midnight?

Tags: php, date, time, timezone

I am learning some PHP. I have a script which checks to see if a JSON file exists. If it does not exist; it will populate it with some YQL and some data. If it exists, it will not do anything as it is better for cache and speed.

In my code; I have this line (currently only doing every 3 hours (10800)):

`if ( !file_exists($cache) || filemtime($cache) < ( time() - 10800 ) ) {`

What I want do is, ***despite the server time***, I want to use the UK GMT timezone and check to see if it is 00.01 past midnight, if it is, that is when I want to update the script. Every day at 00.01 midnight in the UK. Now I have heard PHP supports timezone but I only want it on this script?

This is what I have tried.

```
// TIMEZONE
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
$date = $date();
$timestr = $time();
$timestamp = strtotime('today midnight');

// VARS
$cache = '../media/js/data.json';

// VALIDATION
// -- The cache is new

if ( !file_exists($cache) || filemtime($cache) < ( time() - timestamp ) ) {
```

Comment: It might be worth looking at Cron jobs for this and running the script at 12.01 each day (scheduled tasks if on windows)

Comment: @Izion I think Cron Jobs are not a good approach of development due to maintaining them and documentation and migration of them in my experience.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid, would you not need to use a cron in combination with your current script anyway to have it running each day?. I was just thinking if it was me I would have a cron run each day at roughly 12.01 with the script double checking the UK time before making changes.

Answer (score 0):

another approach would be as mentioned would be cron jobs. you mentioned you want uk time zone , in that case please set your php.ini time zone to UK. this is how you do it
//add this line or replace within your php.ini file

; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
date.timezone = "Europe/London"

and then set the cron job.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using some stuff like that

```
$timezone = "Your timezone";
$tmpTZ = date_default_timezone_get();
date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
// some code to generate the date
date_default_timezone_set($tmpTZ);
```

Putting that in a small function an your ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution will be usage of Cron, just calculate the difference between 2 timezones, and add task on the calculated time

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/